# System.TimeoutException being Thrown when Attempting to Write to Holding Registers using NModbus

Tags: c#, modbus

I'm attempting to write a `Modbus` master program in C# that writes values into the holding registers of a single slave device over a `RTU` serial connection.

```
void SerialTimerTick(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    _sp.WriteLine(inputText.ToString());

    slaveAddress = (byte)slaveAddressNumericUpDown.Value;
    startAddress = (ushort)startAddressNumericUpDown.Value;
    registerAddress = (ushort)registerNumericUpDown.Value;
    targetRegisterValue = (ushort)targetValueNumericUpDown.Value;

    modbusMaster.WriteSingleRegister(slaveAddress, registerAddress, targetRegisterValue);

    SerialTimer.Enabled = false;
    sendButton.Enabled = true;
}
```

The problem is that when I attempt to send the write request to the slave, I get the following error:

> System.TimeoutException: The operation has timed out.

which happens after the program outputs these numbers to the debug console in SharpDevelop three times, indicating three attempts:

- 254
- 120
- 128
- 34
- 32
- 25

To fix it, I've tried using break points to diagnose the problem, and it appears that NModbus is expecting some kind of `ACKNOWLEDGE` response from the slave in order to confirm that the data was sent correctly, only no such response is given.

When I look at my slave's communications feed, I see that something *is* happening on the slave's end when both the master and slave applications are running and my computer is connected to itself using two USB to Serial adapters:

```
Port COM 3 opened.
Port I/O buffers configured.
Port configured 256000,8,N,1
Timeouts configured (100ms/500ms)
Modem status : [CTS_][DSR_RING_]
RX: 0D 0A 0A 06 00 01
RX: 00 01 19 CA
RX: 01 06 00 01 00 01
RX: 19 CA
RX: 01 06 00 01 00 01
```

Instead, what I expected is for the first attempt to succeed and for the 40001 register to change its value from zero to one. I've tried changing NModbus versions, I've tried messing with the timeout and attempt settings of the `IModbusMaster`object and I've also tried removing the exception entirely, which seems to be the only way I've gotten the program to work correctly, however this isn't an acceptable solution in my case.

The only thing I haven't tried so far is changing the slave application I'm using, which is currently the free `PLC` Simulator, which is written in C++ and not C#. This might be part of the problem, but I'm not sure.

I've only been using Modbus for a few weeks, and am working with a rather old version of the NModbus library. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used NModbus, but I have written my own Modbus "stack" in C++ and C# so this answer is based more on my experience with Modbus than on how NModbus works.

There should be a response from Modbus commands EXCEPT when broadcasted (slave address 0).  It should be normal operation for Modbus code to send the request and wait for a response.  If the response is not received in a some specified amount of time, I would expect a timeout error.

Looking at the modbus spec; the write single register function should have an identical request and response ADU (if successful).  It sounds like you are trying to write slave address 1 register 1 with a value 1.  In that case, both the request response ADUs should be "01 06 00 01 00 01 19 CA" ("19 CA" is the correct CRC for this PDU).   I do see what could be data from a request or response, but there seems to be something interfering:

```
RX: 0D 0A (NOT SURE WHAT THIS DATA IS FROM)
RX: 0A 06 00 01 00 01 19 CA (LOOKS CLOSE, BUT ADDRESS IS WRONG)
RX: 01 06 00 01 00 01 19 CA (LOOKS CORRECT)
RX: 01 06 00 01 00 01 (LOOKS CORRECT, BUT INCOMPLETE)
```

Just to test, try a much slower baud rate (9600) and use even parity.  Some USB to Serial converters have driver parameters that can be tweaked.  Do you have termination enabled on both converters (first and last devices terminated)?   Is there a way to configure the NModbus response timeout?

Comment: Hi! Thank you for the response. My apologies for not getting back to you for so long. I'll try that and see what happens. There doesn't appear to be any hardware or driver settings that I can immediately see, but I'll be sure to look into them.

Comment: If you are on Windows using a USB-RS485 converter, many of them use an FTDI chip and the FTDI drivers (even if they are "rebranded").  In device manager, right click on the port, on the port settings tab click the advanced button.